# rails 3 postgreSQL basic 'database does not exist'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

OK, I'm building my first rails 3.0 app and want to test the postgreSQL server as production on my development machine (which is running 10.6). When you create a new app and rake db:migrate it creates sqlite db's for all three environments. Cool. Now I want to learn how to move to production and use postgres. I've used homebrew to install postgres, installed the pg `(env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg)` and `postgres-pr gems`.

I've run rake `db:migrate` in hope that like with sqlite3 it will auto build my production server since I've updated my database.yml (see below).

OK, in my app's folder, I restart the server using '`rails s --environment=production`' and it bails saying it cannot find my production database.

So all the google searches for 'rails 3 postgres install' got me this far, but I appear to be missing something because rails is failing to create the new pg database.

postgres is running as determined by ps.

```
createdb -Omysuperusername -Eutf8 vitae_production
createdb -Omysuperusername -Eutf8 /Users/sam/apps/vitae/db/vitae_production
```

But this directory does not have this database so I'm missing something. What am I overlooking?

this is my database.yml snippet:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: db/vitae_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: mysuperusername
  password:
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here. First of all, you seem to be mixing the SQLite and PostgreSQL format for the `database:` setting in your `database.yml`. With SQLite, you [specify the relative path to the SQLite database file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-an-sqlite3-database) with something like:

```
database: db/vitae_production.sqlite
```

but with PostgreSQL, you [specify the database name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database) with something like this:

```
development:
  database: vitae_development
  username: rails
  ...
```

Then, once `database.yml` is setup, you'd [create the database user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) (if needed) from inside `psql`:

```
psql> create role rails login;
```

and then [let Rails create the database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-database):

```
$ rake db:create
```

Then you should be able to run your migrations to create your initial tables and away you go.

You probably want to read the [`create role`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) documentation to make sure you get the right options. You probably want to be working in the development environment rather than production as well so I changed the names and YAML to reflect that, production is for deployment and I don't think you're deploying anything just yet.

Answer (score 4):

Im'not familiar with rails but you could create your database as a postgres super user and then grant privileges, assuming that in your linux distribution the postgres super user is postgres:

```
su root
su postgres
createdb vitae_production
```

then in postgres grant privileges to another user

```
psql
CREATE USER rails WITH PASSWORD 'myPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE vitae_production TO rails;
ALTER DATABASE vitae_production OWNER TO rails;
```

then your config file should look like this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: vitae_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: rails
  password: myPassword
```